# Unable to upload files to Ubuntu server using Coda FTP client despite user having all permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp

I set up a new Ubuntu server with one user to whom I granted full permissions by adding `jsmith  ALL=(ALL) ALL` to the `/etc/sudoers` file.  The idea being that I would be able to never log in as root and use jsmith all the time for the day-to-day administration of the server.

I want to use [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) to upload files to the server, logging in as jsmith rather than root.

Unfortunately, when I log in to the server under SFTP using root, I can upload files without issues.  If I log in as jsmith, I can connect to the server and navigate all the way up to its root, but if I try to upload a file I get an error:

*[image: Screenshot]*

I suspect I've overlooked something in the configuration, but despite googling the issue I haven't been able to find a solution.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: sudo doesn't have any effect when using sftp.  Do you really want full filesystem access over sftp?

Comment: Yes, I do!  I use that client to work on all my site files, and I want the convenience of being able to upload them to the server when ready without using the command line or having to log in as root.

Comment: Sure - but the *entire* file system?  Why would you need to routinely upload files to / or /bin or /etc or /sbin?

Comment: No! Only up to and including www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to use your daily account for administration – that's what 'root'/'sudo' are for. Giving yourself immediate full access to the entire file system is a **huge** security risk.

---

To use 'sudo' for SFTP in the OpenSSH server, you can edit the "`Subsystem sftp`" line in your `sshd` configuration. Write a script that checks if the user is privileged and executes the original 'sftp-server' with or without 'sudo' depending on the result, then point `sshd` to that script. Make sure you are allowed to execute said 'sftp-server' without requiring a 'sudo' password, otherwise it will not work at all.

Comment: Thanks!  I solved it by doing `chown -R jsmith /var/www/`

Comment: Good. That's a much better choice, given the intended usage.

Comment: Yup.  Although i was wondering whether, for good measure, I should switch jsmith's default group (currently jsmith) to `www-data`too… Haven't quite worked out how group membership interacts with general permissions such as the one I just gave.

Comment: Don't switch the *default* (primary) group. Instead you could add `www-data` to jsmith's secondary groups using `gpasswd`. // In Unix, if you are the owner of an object (file or directory), then your group memberships are not considered at all when checking access.